# No media listed on external devices after enabling DLNA on Windows 10

Tags: windows, audio, music, windows-media-center

I have an old Windows 10 laptop which im using to hold my music library.

All the music is stored on an external drive connected to the laptop.
I right click the `Music` folder under `Documents` and move the location to the external drive folder which holds all my music (this is a root folder of many other folders i.e. E:\Music but i could have E:\Images which i dont share).
When i now click Music folder in Explorer it takes me directly to my music.
I enabled Media Streaming Options and can see my devices listed (following this article https://pureinfotech.com/turn-pc-dlna-media-server-windows-10/)
The remaining settings i left to default.

I turn on an external device and navigate to equivalent area to browse for music (so this could be an app on my phone, TV etc) - all on the same network.

All the devices show the Media Library folder but if i go into All Music or All Artists its empty.

I turned off the firewall and same issue.

Thinking it may be sharing or permissions i went to the HDD holding the music and shared it and changed permissions to Everyone for the single folder.

I have restarted the computer a couple of times too.

I can go to another PC and see the folder and contents i.e. in the run command i can type \myLaptop\Music and the folders with music files are found.

Am i missing a step to enable this to be available on other devices?